# Looking for a efficient way of solving a matrix which is function of some variable

Tags: equation-solving, matrix, linear-algebra

What is the efficient way to solve the matrix having a dependency on some varaible `f`. I have a simple matrix `g` which is dependent on `f`. Need to find for what value of  `f`, the determinat of the matrix goes to zero. In reality I am dealing with a problem of size 1000 cross 1000 which is having a dependency on `f`. I dont want to extract the symbolc determinant, and use NSolve to find the roots which satisfy the Det equatio. This method fails for matrix of large dimensions. I am looking for the methods which  is effective  to solve this matrix irrespective  of matrix  dimensions. I have tried a method below, which is not elegant. But this method did not slove my problem.

```
frange = N[Subdivide[0, 1000, 10000]];
g = {{2*f^2 + 3.6*f^2, 192}, {876, 21.8*f^2 + 33.3*f^2}};
c = Table[
   First@#/Last@# &@SingularValueList[g /. f -> frange[[i]]], {i, 1, 
    Length[frange]}];
ListLogLinearPlot[{frange, c}, Joined -> True, PlotRange -> All]
PeakDetect[c]
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could use [`FindRoot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot)? The trick is to know how to differentiate the determinant of a matrix, which is:

$$\frac{d \det (g(x))}{dx} = \det\left(g(x)\right) \
\mathrm{tr}\left(g(x)^{-1}.g'(x)\right)$$

Your example:

```
g = {{2*f^2 + 3.6*f^2, 192}, {876, 21.8*f^2 + 33.3*f^2}};
```

In order to avoid expanding out the symbolic determinant, define:

```
m[f_?NumericQ] = g;
m'[f_?NumericQ] = D[g, f];
```

Then, use FindRoot:

```
FindRoot[Det[m[x]], {x, 10}, Jacobian -> {{Det[m[x]]Tr[Inverse[m[x]] . m'[x]]}}]
```

> {x -> 4.83188}

Answer (score 1):

The type of dependence in `f` is critical here. For your example, it amounts to calculating a generalized eigenvalue.

```
g = {{2*f^2 + 3.6*f^2, 192}, {876, 21.8*f^2 + 33.3*f^2}};
{A0, A1, A2} = CoefficientArrays[g, f] // Normal;
eigs = Eigenvalues[{A0, -Flatten /@ A2}];
```

which is such that

```
Det[g /. f -> Sqrt[eigs[[1]]]]
```

is numerically zero, which corresponds to the solution in the range you are looking for.

More generally, if you have a single variable `f` that appears polynomially in the matrix then its determinant is also a polynomial in that variable and you can solve for its roots as in

```
Solve[Det[g] == 0, f]
```

Comment: Does this method work for  matrix of all dimensions?

Comment: Does this method work for  matrix of all dimensions? And I didnt understood  the second line in your answer.

Comment: It works as long as the matrix is square and the dependence on the one variable is linear. Your matrix is linear in `f^2`, and the second line is extracting the coefficient of the `f^2` term, that is `A2`.

Comment: what If  some terms are  having terms `f^3` and some terms `f^2`, it does not work?

Comment: It may, if you are able to restate your dependence as linear by growing your dimensions then you have a generalized eigenvalue problem. But that would have to be studied carefully. More generally, if all you have is one variable and the dependence is polynomial, then the determinant is a polynomial on that variable. In principle, this amounts to finding the roots of a polynomial in a single variable, which should be workable. I will change the answer to have that addressed.